# jquery click() event runs repeatedly

Tags: jquery, events, click

I have a jQuery question:

I have an "ADD" button that adds text to the database via AJAX call ($.post()...). The problem is, items are getting repeatedly added. For example:

After page loads: User clicks "ADD" button:

- the first time, it adds an item.
- a seconds time, it adds an item and then adds it again (total 2 items)
- a thrid time, it adds an item and then adds it again and than again (total 3 items)
- etc...

This is a problem as the data is duplicating.

I've narrowed down the problem:

```
 $(document).ready(function()
 {
  // set event handler for Add button
  bindAddButtonEventListener();
 });

 // set event handler for Add button
 function bindAddButtonEventListener()
 {
  // event handler for the add button
  $("#addRecord").click(function()
  {
   openPopUpBox();

   enablePopUpBoxControls();

   // event handler for Submit button on admin Popup box. Submits data to database
   $("#editPopUp #submitChanges").click(function(event)
   {
    addNewRecord();
   });
  });
 }

 // this method will submit a new record to the server, using AJAX post
 function addNewRecord()
 {
  var obj = buildJSONobject();

  $.post("admin/addRecordToDatabase", obj, function(data)
  {
   displayServerValidation(data);

   cancelPopUpChanges();
   getCatagoriesItems();
  });

  disablePopUpBoxControls();
 }

 // this unbinds the events for the popup box controls
 function disablePopUpBoxControls()
 {
  // unbind event handler for button
  $("#editPopUp #submitChanges").unbind("click", bindEditButtonEventListener);
  //$("#editPopUp #submitChanges").unbind("click", bindAddButtonEventListener);

  // unbind event handler for button
  $("#editPopUp #cancelEdit").unbind("click", enablePopUpBoxControls);
 }
```

For some reason, inside bindAddButtonEventListener(), when this code runs:

```
   $("#editPopUp #submitChanges").click(function(event)
   {
    addNewRecord();
   });
```

addNewRecord() is called again the second time and a third time, the third time and then again. I can't figure out how to stop it from doing it. I thought that unbinding would help, but it doesn't seem to. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is this all your code? Sounds like you rebind the click handler somewhere after the Ajax call. Do you call `bindAddButtonEventListener` somewhere else? Btw. `$("#editPopUp #submitChanges").unbind("click", bindEditButtonEventListener);` will have no effect, because you never bind `bindEditButtonEventListener` to the click event. You bind an anonymous function *inside* this function to the click event, but not the function itself.

Comment: Vivin, this is not all of my code. Based on the answers below, I do realize that the un/binding is where the problem was. Thanks much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your main problem is here:

```
// unbind event handler for button
$("#editPopUp #submitChanges").unbind("click", bindEditButtonEventListener);
```

This doesn't actually unbind anything, because it wasn't ever bound to that function, for example:

```
$("#editPopUp #submitChanges").click(function(event)
{
 addNewRecord();
});
```

This binds an anonymous function (key point being you can't reference it like you want later), instead since you're not using `event`, bind it directly, like this:

```
$("#editPopUp #submitChanges").click(addNewRecord);
```

Then when you call [`.unbind()`](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) you need to again reference that function:

```
$("#editPopUp #submitChanges").unbind("click", addNewRecord);
```

---

That's the fix, as for the "why?"...well since it wasn't being unbound, it was just racking up a new event handler each time.  Every time you clicked `#addRecord`, it was adding *another* save handler on the `#editPopUp` and `#submitChanges` element click events, properly unbinding as I have above should prevent this.

Comment: oh man... this is so right! I was binding them incorrectly too, i was doing ...click(blah()); instead of ...click(blah); and that is what was killing me. I will be reading more about this to help me out. Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are using unbind incorrectly. Try removing the second parameter "bindEditButtonEventListender".

So use instead:

```
$("#editPopUp #submitChanges").unbind("click");
```

Comment: This would unbind *all* `click` event handlers, so be careful, if there are any *other* `click` handlers (I assume there are given the names) it will remove/break these.

Answer (score 2):

Your unbinding this event 'bindEditButtonEventListener' but you never actually bind it as you bind an anonymous method to the #submitChanges click event.